# Identifying lines with more than one @ symbol

Tags: perl

Given an input such as (but not always in this exact format)

> an@example.commailto:an@example.com

What's the most efficient way to test a line for the presence of more than one @ symbol ?

Comment: I don't see how this question can be closed on the basis of being "Too broad". How many interpretations can there be?!

Comment: Exactly.  It is a very specific question and I have a very specific example string !  Thanks for all the positive answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The canonical way of counting characters in a string is to use `tr///`.

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $s = 'an@example.commailto:an@example.com';

my $n = $s =~ tr/@//;

say $n;
```

**output**

```
2
```

So you can write

```
if ( $s =~ tr/@// > 1 ) {
  # do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( $str =~ /@.*@/ )
```

will match any line that has an `@` followed by any number of characters (even zero) and then `@`.

Comment: `/@.*?@/` or `/@[^@\n]*@/` (or `/@.*?@/s` or `/@[^@]*@/` if the OP really meant test the string, not test a line)

Comment: @ysth: I don't see how the non-greedy modifier helps.

Comment: @Borodin: it doesn't change whether there's a match, but it does make it more efficient, which the question specifically asked for